# Run a C# exe with parameters that is to start another application and get output from console

Tags: c#, console, output

I have an exe which has some parameters- path of another application and some files to be opened from that application. There would be an output as part of that application which would be displayed in the console of my exe.
But i am unable to get the output from the console.
I have the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("\"" + dllpath + "\\newapplication.exe" + "\"");
Process p = new Process();
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
```

The process starts successfully, and then i have to open a file in the process which happens through another class. So after the file opened, some extraction happens and the result is displayed on the console.
When i give `p.WaitForExit();` nothing happens other than starting the application! How do i acheive to retreive the output on StandardOutput as per my code? Need Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
string outputProcess = "";
string errorProcess = "";

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();
    outputProcess = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    errorProcess = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Remember to use the `using` statement when you have an `IDisposable` object

Comment: It starts the process. But i want the process to do some extractions with a file.. which is not happening at all. The process just remains open and does nothing.